# Use Chromium depot tools to fetch a specific revision

Tags: webrtc, chromium

I've been googling about and haven't turned up anything, so here goes. I would like to use the chromium repo tools to fetch WebRTC at a specific revision rather than the head revision.

I've also been looking at the depot tool scripts including `depot_tools/getch_configs/webrtc.py` along with the depot tools help pages but there doesn't appear to be anything revision specific in there either.

Does anyone know how I could do something like `fetch webrtc @ acbd123...` to checkout a specific revision? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can go to ``src\third_party\webrtc`` then launch git bash and checkout a specific version or fetch the desired version. webrtc is a third-party dependency and will have it's own local and remote repo, so you can do so independently

Comment: Hi @Asesh, will that run the risk of not updating any of the thirdparty stuff needed by WebRTC to the associated revisions for the desired WebRTC revision?

Comment: As long as the third-party dependencies of WebRTC are in it's repo, it should be fine. If it's not in their repo then you will have to manually update the third-party dependencies of webrtc